# jQuery iteration return conditional

Tags: jquery, html

I was looking at the jQuery docs and came across the .each function. This itself is fine, but in the example they used there is a return statement condition that I do not understand. To me, it seems that the code shouldn't run unless the 'val' is 'three'. In the comments however, it says that the program will not run past 'three'. That is the part I do not understand. Here is the markup followed by the jQuery.

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>

<script>
    var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
    var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };

    jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
        $( "#" + val ).text( "Mine is " + val + "." );

        // Will stop running after "three"
        return ( val !== "three" );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iteration will continue because the function is returning `true`. It stops when it's returning `false` when `val === "three"`.

Comment: Good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here I used a simple quick "if" instead of the other item.

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<script>
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };
jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
    if (val == "three") {
        $( "#" + val ).text( "Mine is " + val + "." );
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: The code in your answer is not equivalent to the code in the question